# Characterizing hexagon coordinates in a different coordinate system

Tags: geometry, vectors

I have a line going between two given points $\mathbf{S}$ and $\mathbf{E}$. I want to obtain the coordinates of the 6 points of the hexagon that lies in the plane perpendicular to the vector $(\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{E})$ that contains $\mathbf{S}$.

To solve this, I denoted the hexagon points $\mathbf{P}_k, k=1,\ldots, 6$ in the plane with $\mathbf{S}$ and noted that

$$
(\mathbf{P}_k - \mathbf{S})\cdot (\mathbf{E} - \mathbf{S}) = 0, \forall k.
$$

I know that the norm $|\mathbf{P}_k - \mathbf{S}| = d, \forall k$ and that the norm of the line is $|\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{E}| = r$ and so using Pythagoras gives

$$
|\mathbf{P}_k - \mathbf{S}|^2 + |\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{E}|^2 = |\mathbf{P}_k - \mathbf{E}|^2 \iff \\
d^2 + r^2 = |\mathbf{P}_k - \mathbf{E}|^2, \forall k.
$$

Moreover, I also know that if the origin of the coordinate system was $\mathbf{S}$ the points in the plane can be characterized as
$$
(x_k, y_k, 0) = \left( d\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}k\right),
                       d\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}k\right),
                       0\right), k=1,\ldots,6
$$

So far I obtained two out of three equations that I need to uniquely determine the points $\mathbf{P}_k$. My question is, how should I derive the third needed equation?

Comment: Such hexagons are infinitely many.

Comment: Let us assume that the distance from $\mathbf{S}$ to one of the hexagon points is known (d) and that it is not rotated with respect to the in S plane x and y axes (so the first point lies on the x axis, the next at 60 degrees counter-clockwise, and so on). Would that be sufficient to make it unique?

Comment: But how is the (xy) frame in S plane rotated with respect to (xyz) coordinates?

Comment: The plane is characterized by the unit normal (which can be found from the line itself as $\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{E}/|\mathbf{S} - \mathbf{E}|$). I guess taking the dot product between this vector and the cartesian x, y and z unit vectors would give the orientation.

Comment: In principle, you could choose ANY direction in S plane as that of x axis. If you don't have other constraints.

Comment: I understand your point. Would it be an idea to set the x axis as the unit vector from S to one of the points P_k and the y axis as the one perpendicular to that?

Comment: Yes: once you choose two perpendicular unit vectors $\mathbf{\hat x}$ and $\mathbf{\hat y}$ on plane $S$, then you can rewrite your last formula as $$ \mathbf{P}_k=d\cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}k\right)\mathbf{\hat x}+
                       d\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{6}k\right)\mathbf{\hat y}$$